# Grails Spring Security Differences between Requestmap and securityConfig/mappings

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

## SETUP

I have a grails 2.0 app with the following grails spring security pluggins

- spring-security-core 2.0-RC2
- spring-security-ldap 2.0-RC2
- spring-security-ui 1.0-RC1

I am using the the database based approach to secure urls via **Requestmap** approach

## PROBLEM

I have an application in production that does not seem to be picking up the latest url configs that I have put in the Requestmap table. For example:

I had the following url mapping **/home** set to **IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY** to allow everybody to go to home. I have deleted that database entry and if I run the app locally (pointing against prod db) and when trying to go to home I get an access denied which is good, exactly what I wanted. Additionally, if I go to **/securityInfo/mappings** that url is not  displayed because it no longer exists in the database.

But if I go to the prodcution application which is pointing to the same database and go to **/home** I am still alowed to access it !!! even though that rule is no longer on the db. Also if I look at **/securityInfo/mappings** that url mapping **/home** it's still displaying but yet if I go to requestmap/search and look for it, it's not found.

To me it seems like the permissions work not based on Requestmap but based on what securityConfig/mappings states.

## QUESTION

My question is how come the data in securityInfo/mappings does not match what's on the Requestmap table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 2 sites running off the same db? The result in the production site will be cached by hibernate

Comment: So is there a specific hibernate setting that I should use so that it does not cache my Requestmap table? Otherwise, If I add or remove urls after the application is deployed I have to redeploy the app.